# Is it possible to use List<T>.Contains(...)?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to to create a generic cache class that will hold a list of objects, 
 and will expose a method that enables to check if an instance of an object is already cached based on Id property:

```
public class CacheService<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    private List<T> _data = new List<T>();

    public void Check(T obj)
    {
        if (_data.Contains(r => r.Id.Equals(obj.Id))
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}

public class BaseModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting a compiler error on the `Contains()` command, saying:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'T' because it is not a delegate type

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: `Contains` takes a *possible element* to search for, not a *predicate*.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use Linq:

```
bool contains = _data.Any(r => r.Id.Equals(obj.Id));
```

or [`List.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx):

```
bool contains = _data.Exists(r => r.Id.Equals(obj.Id));
```

Comment: Good call for `Exists` - I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: Thanks! `Any()` solves my problem. However, `Exists()` does not exists in my auto-complete list. In what namespace does it live?

Comment: @Liel: `List.Exists` is an old .NET 2 method in `List<T>`(link above). So it should be visible.

Comment: Apparently the reason for me not seeing the `Exists()` extension is that I am writing a PCL library with a subset of .NET. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Use the LINQ function `Any` instead of `Contains`. For `List<T>`, the `Contains` method is defined to take a `T`.